# Search for VM under different list of HyperV host using python

Tags: python

I'm very new to coding with python and want to use this skillset to enhance my work as an IT administrator taking care of hundreds of VMs and its HyperV hosts.

What I want to do is to generate a list of VMs hosted on each HyperV ( already done via PowerShell), and then make use of this list to do a search for a VM using python. I know that this can be done with Microsoft Virtual Machine Manager but unfortunately, we don't have this tool.

Supposedly my list appears like this;

## HyperV 1

VM1

VM2

VM3

VM4

What I want to achieve is when I do a python search for "VM4", I need to know the host for it as well. Currently, when I do a search for VM4, I print the 10 lines above it.

This is my PowerShell script for generating the list of VMs under each HyperV

```
write-Host "Get list of VM on listed Hyper-Vs"
$enddate = (Get-Date).ToString("ddMMyyyy")
$filename = $enddate + "-vmlist.txt"

$hostlist = 1..137 | ForEach-Object {"MyHostname$_"}
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

foreach ($host_vm in $host_list) {
    echo "---$host_vm---" 
    Write-Host "Populating $host_vm..."
    Get-VM -ComputerName $host_vm | ft State, Name -AutoSize
}
Write-Host "Completed"
```

Comment: Hi. If you aleready done it with powershell....please supply your PS code sample in order to better understand the usecase...also : please supply a sample code of the python you already tried

Comment: Hi, roughly added the script to generate the list, but not the search portion as my scripts are in office. I haven't really tried on the python portion as I am clueless about how to start. I read somewhere that I can open the text file with python, save each line generated as a python list and then I can explore from there.

source: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001721.htm

Comment: Okay. The problem here is the translation of the Get-VM command (all the rest is simple prints, getttime and for loop)....there is no "simple" python for this. but there is some library. I suggest you to take a look at : https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/ and https://github.com/lgeeklee/python-vmstats which is based on the first one.